# SWTBotEclipseEditor title and tooltip text

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

how to find the title and tooltip text of SWTBotEclipseEditor.getText() method gives the text inside SWTBotEclipseEditor.

[image]

```
SWTBotEclipseEditor editor = bot.editorByTitle("testFoo.txt").toTextEditor();
String title =  editor.???   //I want title which is testFoo.txt
String toolTip = editor.getToolTipText();  //not giving 'tooltip text'
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround,I used `editor.getReference().getTitle()` or 
`editor.getReference().getTitleToolTip()`.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/373784/